# Unable to get the location of the bucket in s3

Tags: amazon-s3, location

I am sending the following request

```
GET http://bucketname.s3.amazonaws.com/?location 
Host: bucketname.s3.amazonaws.com 
x-amz-date:  20170531T082529Z
Authorization: AWS
```

I am getting following error

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Error>
    <Code>NoSuchKey</Code>
    <Message>The specified key does not exist.</Message>
    <Key>?location</Key>
    <RequestId>7E63980AAE</RequestId>
    <HostId>HostID</HostId>
</Error>
```

Seems like it is trying to get the object with ?location name. but As per Amazon API page http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/API/RESTBucketGETlocation.html
it should return the location of the bucket

Comment: I think you are trying to access region-specific bucket with no region specified. Check the following link to see details: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/UsingBucket.html

Comment: I am trying to get the location of the bucket. I am passing the region as us-east-1 for listing buckets.and after that i am trying to get the location of the bucket which is failing. Yes my bucket region is different from us-east-1

Comment: What does the IAM policy for the user trying to access this bucket look like?  Also in the docs it has the GET as /?location and nothing in front it with just host header setup. Maybe the api is confusing the the request for an s3 object in the bucket?